# SFML shaders (GLSL) calling texture2D() has side effects?

Tags: c++, shader, sfml

I am trying to use two textures with different resolutions (and thus different texture coordinates) in my shader. However, if I call `texture2D()` (or `texture()`, doesn't matter) on the second texture with anything other than `gl_TexCoord[0].xy`, the output becomes distorted, even if the result of the lookup is not used anywhere.

First texture, aka `texture`:

[image]

Second texture, aka `noise`:

[image]

Distorted image. The `gl_Color` passed to the vertex shader is white on the left and black on the right so somehow this image is a result of `pixel * gl_Color * some_weird_color_shift`

[image]

Vertex shader. I just started with copying `gl_TexCoord[0]` and sending its interpolated value to fragment.

```
varying vec4 noiseTexCoord;

void main()
{
    // transform the vertex position
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

    // transform the texture coordinates
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    noiseTexCoord = gl_TexCoord[0];

    // forward the vertex color
    gl_FrontColor = vec4(gl_Color.z, gl_Color.z, gl_Color.z, 1);
}
```

Fragment shader. With the `bugger` commented out, this draws the `noise` texture.

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D noise;

varying vec4 noiseTexCoord;

void main()
{
    // lookup the pixel in the texture
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);

    // vec4 bugger = texture2D(noise, noiseTexCoord);
    vec4 noise = texture2D(noise, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    
    // gl_Color is unused

    gl_FragColor = noise;
}
```

If I uncomment the `bugger` variable, the resulting image will be the distorted one, no matter what is written to `gl_FragColor`. It doesn't matter if I assign a `pixel`, `noise` or some hardcoded color to it.

I would not be surprised if `noiseTexCoord` contained some weird value, but I thought the `texture2D` is just a lookup without side effects. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `noiseTexCoord` is `vec4` that I am trying to pass to `texture2D` that expects a `vec2`. Thus the fragment shader failed to compile.

The proper expression should be:

```
vec4 bugger = texture2D(noise, noiseTexCoord.xy);
```

Which behaves as expected.